# How can I solve a non-linear differential equations system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

I have the following system of differential equations,
$$\ddot{r}-\dot{\theta}^2=0$$
$$r\ddot{\theta}+2\dot{r}\dot{\theta}=\ddot{r}$$
how can I solve it?

Comment: I think you are missing r in the first equation, second term

Comment: And quite possibly the right side of the second equation should be zero. Then this looks like $\ddot z=0$ was transformed into polar coordinates $z=re^{iθ}$.

Comment: r and $\theta$ could be function of t. I wonder if we could have a good guess.